# File group has changed without me changing it

Tags: chown, groups, ownership

I was working with a file today that I don't own. I copied it to a /tmp folder, gave myself sudo permissions and then changed the owner to myself using chown. I then made my changes.

Afterwords I returned it to the original owner and copied it back to the original directory, overwriting the file already there.

At some point during this  the group of the file has changed. I know I haven't deliberately changed the group, I only requested the owner change.

Can anybody shed some light on what may have happened? Is there also any way to see the times/dates a file had the owner/group changed? (I doubt it but it's worth asking!)

Thanks,
James

Comment: What group was it originally and what is it now?

Comment: I believe the group was www-data and is now eprints. the user was changed from eprints to my username and changed back to eprints.